# The first attempt at a riddle

Tags: riddle

I've been browsing this place for a couple days off/on for a while -- couldn't particularly solve anything because I just don't really have the experience (plus I don't really know any of the cipher stuff), but I decided to try my hand at making a riddle anyway! Apologies for messing up the format / tagging if I do. I'm sure you nice people will get it fairly easily, though.

> I stand at the front of my formation, pointing at the enemy.
>
> What sounds like a boulder rushes towards me, but I stay strong.
>
> Even when I get knocked back, I rise again.
>
> The enemy struck hard, but resilient I am,
>
> standing tall and enduring this,
>
> hoping that next time they'll spare me.
>
> What am I?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! The formatting and tags are fine, well done there. This looks like a good first riddle, and the best way to gain experience here is through making and solving. If you want a headstart though, I suggest looking through the highest voted riddles, and for ciphers [I wrote a guide for exactly this purpose](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52118/guide-to-codes-and-ciphers/52119#52119) to help new users. Good luck in the future! :)

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look. Any tips for solving?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour!](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour)**) Very good first riddle - nicely hinted to a clear correct answer. Glad to see you here, and know that experience is just a matter of time. :)

Comment: @TheThirdMage there's a link somewhere in there to a post where it talks about how you can recognise a cipher from the ciphertext (it should appear on the right hand side). generally there should be a hint somewhere in there too. On puzzling its most likely either rot13 or vigenere, so I recommend  taking a good luck at them first

Comment: It was pretty easy (coming from someone who's not so great themselves), but I definitely applaud you for this excellent first attempt! I personally am not creative enough to write puzzles, so I'm a veteran lurker. It can take awhile to come across something solvable. A suggestion? Think more intrigue. You've definitely got the first-person riddle format down and have some good metaphors, but you could safely go a little more vague without sacrificing solvability.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it this time.

You are

> a skittle/ a bowling pin (I call em skittles but apparently that's just me XD )

I stand at the front of my formation, pointing at the enemy.

> The skittle at the front, facing the incoming bowling ball

What sounds like a boulder rushes towards me, but I stay strong.

> The bowling ball misses

Even when I get knocked back, I rise again.

> When a skittle gets knocked over it is resurrected

The enemy struck hard, but resilient I am,

> The bowling ball hit the skittles but not all fell down

standing tall and enduring this,

> The skittle is still standing

hoping that next time they'll spare me.

> If all skittles are knocked over the second attempt its a spare (like the wordplay)

Comment: I've never seen it called a skittle before xD

Comment: @TheThirdMage I'm english :P What do you call it?

Comment: American here, simply called bowling pins. Logic is sound though, got the right answer even through dialect differences.