# Hidden message #1

Tags: cipher

One day I was visiting an unknown forest and I found some mysterious message written on the trees. The message was

> WEZI SUZNKX JFWYM
>   QT BRX AMPP GLH

Help me to decode the hidden message.

Comment: @MOehm will you tell me how to make strong ciphers

Comment: Hmmm. I'd start by looking at some of the most upvoted questions with the [tag:cipher] tag and their answers. Getting better at cracking codes will make you better at designing them. Often, the trick isn't to create a strong unbreakable cipher, but to combine simple ciphers or combine ciphers with stories or steganography. Remember, this site is about puzzles. It is more important that the puzzle is fun to solve than to have an unbreakable cipher.

Comment: I've said in a now deleted part of my comment that your cipher will be easy to solve for seasoned PSE denizens. That's true, because your cipher is based on a common simple cipher that many will try first. But your cipher has a little twist, and that's nice. It's a snack-sized cipher puzzle and there's nothing wrong with that. There's always a danger to make a cipher too obscure. On the other hand, this site is also about finding out what works and what doesn't work in puzzles and you you can't do that without occasionally creating something that doesn't work.

Comment: Finally, here are two posts you might find useful. The first one [outlines some basic ciphers and methods for solving them](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52118/guide-to-codes-and-ciphers/52119#52119). The second one details [things  you should avoid](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1717/code-puzzles-what-not-to-do) in cipher puzzles. This one is often linked as comment to cipher puzzles that don't seem to provide a suitable way of getting the first step towards breaking it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

@MOehm is right: the idea is:

> go back with number of letters in the word itself

WEZI SUZNKX JFWYM

> SAVE MOTHER EARTH

QT BRX AMPP GLH

> OR YOU WILL DIE

Comment: How did you figure it out

Comment: I figured by first QT there were few possibilities for this like at, to, or etc containing two letters and should match for both letters