# Hidden message #2

Tags: cipher

One day I was going to a temple. On the path I met an old person who was giving cards to everyone. On card there is a strange message written.

**Will you help me to read the message?**

> [image]

Hint

> [Hidden message #1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/57376/42608)

Comment: Please don't spoiler the actual puzzle itself. Spoilers should only be used for hints and solutions.

Comment: @deusovi  i will keep it in mind

Comment: It is a snack size puzzle you can eat it in the morning

Comment: You meet a lot of old man dude. Whats up with that?

Comment: @prog_SAHIL yeh :) that is interesting thing because old is gold

Comment: It reminds me of this puzzle as a created one (so props for it), based on the information in ciphers (for beginners as well as for advanced puzzlers) of the PSE site (pigpen cipher)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very partial answer. I used brute force to get this. Just hope it’s correct.

---

I think the answer is

> Nice to meet you

When you decipher the pigpen, you get

> RMGIUQQIIXULR

Then you do rot-22 (equivalent to taking each letter four letters back) and get

> NICEQMMEETQHN

I used rot-3 on QM (basically taking each letter in UQ one letter back) to get

> TP

And rot-7 on QHN (that’s the same as taking each letter in ULR three letters ahead) to get

> XOU

Did a little change (P to O & X to Y) to give me

> Nice to meet you

Answer (score 4):

First answer here (partial answer), feel free to edit.

Using Pigepen cipher we can find :

> RMGIVQQIIXVLR then using the ^ at delimeter taking RMGI, and using caesar code with key = 4 (because there is 4 letter in the word, we find NICE but the rest of the text don't match)

Comment: You are on the way

Answer (score 1):

What i did to create this question is
 I shifted the letters according to length of the word.

```
NICE + 4 letter shift  gave me RMGI.   
 TO +2 letter shift gave me UQ.   
 MEET +4 letter shift gave me QIIX.   
 YOU -3 letter shift gave me ULR.   
 Finally i got RMGIUQQIIXULR
```

.