# Hidden message #3

Tags: cipher

So one day after an interview at Stack Exchange, I received a letter. In the letter there is a card, on which strange letters are written.

**Will you help me to decode the message?**

```
ZQX BTH BYHWTSK.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is

> YOU ARE AWESOME.

Encryption method:

> shift the $n$th letter of each word forward by $n$ places in the alphabet. Thus, in YOU, we shift the Y one place to Z, the O two places to Q, and the U three places to X. The same goes for the other words.

I figured this out by

> looking at [your](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/57376/5373) previous [puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/57415/5373) :-) You're using some kind of letter-shifting idea each time, just varying the details.