# Another Cipher/Cryptogram(?)

Tags: cipher

***Here's another dumb cipher I actually tried hard on encrypting!***

X ZXBPXO ZFMEBO FP LKB LC QEB PFJMIBPQ BKZOVMQFLK IXKDRXDBP

***And here's some hints:***

1.

> It has something to do with the number 23.

2.

> I love Wikipedia. So much that this is actually part of a wikipedia article.

3.

> The article is about a "language."

4.

> Here's a joke. It's about what this cipher has:
>
>
> I got fired at my typewriting job because I didn't put in enough shifts.

5.

> Hint 4 is about that "23" I was talking about.

I hope that wasn't too much hints. If this is unsolvable or just really weird, dumb, or too hard for any one i'll try to simplify or add more hints.

Comment: For your future puzzles you might want to wait before giving hints - see if people get stuck first :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is *very* easy. It's simply

> a rot23 of "A CAESAR CIPHER IS ONE OF THE SIMPLEST ENCRYPTION LANGUAGES".

Comment: I just found out about it and wanted to give it a go. c: Anyways, congrats you solved it :D

Comment: @KoolKidz112 First, thanks for contributing—it can be a bit daunting! Second, *definitely* write the kind of puzzles YOU want to write; your passion will come through. But, third, do keep your audience in mind; while Caesar ciphers may be new to you, they're well known to many here.  See the [Guide to Codes and Ciphers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52118/guide-to-codes-and-ciphers) post for specific information on ciphers that PSE folk tend to be well versed in, and [Code Puzzles: What (Not) To Do?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1717) for more general tips.

Comment: Finally, check out [When should I add hints to my puzzle?](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5005) and its various answers ([this one](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5012) in particular) for guidance on how, and when, to use hints.  Welcome again, and hope your next puzzle sees great success!