# Mineral of Mystery

Tags: riddle

> A brilliant showing of a glare
>
> The space kind has some very tough flair
>
> Fake ones manufactured and taken by fools
>
> Because people that aren't "Adamas" wants to look cool

**What is it?**

---

Hint:

> The word "Adamas" is Greek for "unbreakable".

Comment: Welcome to PSE, Xavier. I've edited out your meta question as it's not part of the puzzle. If you want help solving a specific puzzle, or type of puzzle, you can ask it separately here (if it's more about how things work on PSE than puzzles themselves, then [meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/) is the better place). You're also welcome to pick people's brains in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14524/the-sphinxs-lair).

Comment: [continued...] If you want more general help, your best bet is probably just reading through existing puzzles/answers, though there are also a few guide type questions/answers here as well that may help (eg. for [ciphers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/52118) and [cryptic crossword clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

are you

> diamonds

A brilliant showing of a glare

> they reflect the light really brightly

The space kind has some very tough flair

> i haven't figured out if there's any connection yet, sadly. The internet didn't provide much help, either. oops

Fake ones manufactured and taken by fools

> fake diamonds can only be distinguished if you know how to

Because people that aren't "Adamas" wants to look cool

> I have a close attention to "Adamas" - unbreakable, diamonds are the hardest material. Also people usually wear diamonds to look cool and rich.

Comment: Black diamonds are found in meteorites and originated in supernovae, they are extremely though (even for diamonds)

Comment: @SilverCookies That's just a theory, from what I know there is nothing proven. There are also researches that they come from radioactivity.

Comment: Given that there is virtually no way to distinguish an artificial (reasonaby priced) diamond from a genuine one (with [artificially inflated](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/79848/is-it-true-that-the-price-of-diamonds-is-based-on-a-monopoly) price), the clue of "taken by fools" seems completely backwards for this answer.

Comment: You can tell diamonds that are real from diamonds that are fake. It just takes knowledge of the properties of diamond. Especially since diamonds that are real and natural have been described as more valued by jewelers, meaning that people have told them apart before.

Comment: Answerers putting their solutions in spoiler tags is of little benefit if people then give the answer away in the comments.  Try being more indirect in alluding to the answer instead of saying or referencing it directly, or using [ROT-13](http://www.rot13.com/) encoding or similar if you must, to preserve the mystery for future would-be solvers. :)