# Looking for a word

Tags: word, cipher, knowledge

I'm looking for a word.
Use all the skills listed on the tags.

> do  hold  you 
>   hand  under  knee 
>   wonders  lips  honey  jam  lingers  
>   inside  right 
>   vast  unique  light  
>  
>   just  outside   
>   alone  like  universe  
>   don't  know  
>   might practise climbing life

Comment: Not sure the "riddle" tag applies here, so I'm removing it. Feel free to re-add it if I'm wrong. OTOH I've added the "word" tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taking the first letter of each word and decrypting with rot19 gives

> war
> and
> peace
> bk
> one
> ch
> ten
> wd
> five

Meaning the word is

> The fifth word in chapter 10 in the first book of war and peace

Which, unless I've messed up finding it, is

> 'promise' from the line 'Prince Vasili kept the promise'

Comment: Damn phone call, I've been beaten by a few seconds :-)

Comment: @xhienne wow incredibly close! Have a +1 anyway, the phone call wasn't your fault :)

Comment: wow! I was on this page when both of you answered back to back within seconds of each other. Great work!

Comment: @jwi thanks! Only feedback I have to give really is that perhaps somewhere there could be a hint as to why the cipher was ROT 7 (or to decrypt with ROT 19) cos trial and error can be a bit tedious. Apart from that nice puzzle!

Comment: haha it was actually done using Caesar cipher, shifted 7. But you guys got it in a different way than I thought. Anyways, Noted !!!

Comment: @jwi [caesar cipher is the same as ROT](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/52144/18250) ;)

Answer (score 7):

I think the word is

> promise

Here is how to find it:

> Take the first letter of every word. Turn line skips into spaces.
>  This yields: "dhy huk wlhjl ir vul jo alu dk mpcl"
>
>  Now, shift each letter by 19 positions.
>  This yields: "war and peace bk one ch ten wd five"
>
>  Then, look at the fifth word of [War and Peace, book 1, chapter 10](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/War_and_Peace/Book_One#CHAPTER_X) and you'll find "promise".